# JQuery get text within a specific set of p tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem trying to obtain text between a certain set of `<p>` tags using JQuery - here is the html that I currently have:

```
<div class="mainarea">
    <p>
        <strong>Location: </strong>
    </p>

    <!-- display search results -->
    <p>
        You searched for
        <strong>"xyz"</strong>.
    </p>
```

I'm trying to get the text within the second set of `<p>` tags (You searched for ...), but I keep getting the text from the first `<p>` tag (Location ...).

So far I have this function:

`$('.mainarea p')`, which returns "Location..." and have tried to add the .text() function to it, but this doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) or [:eq selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```
$('.mainarea p').eq(1).text();
```

Using selector:

```
$('.mainarea p:eq(1)').text();
```

> Note: Used [.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/) as mentioned in the text. To get innerHTML use [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

```js
$('body').html($('.mainarea p').eq(1).html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainarea">
  <p>
    <strong>Location: </strong>
  </p>

  <!-- display search results -->
  <p>
    You searched for <strong>"xyz"</strong>.
  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly we can use the following code given bellow

```
console.log("value is"+$('.mainarea p:last').html()) ;
```

Here your p position at last so i am using this approached.If  p is not last element then we can use .eq()to set the index or get the index.